# How to prevent Matplotlib from overwriting rcParams when using styles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use a style that is not the default matplotlib. It removes the rcParams that I have set. the rcParams work when I don't include the style line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 8]
```

How do I prevent the style from overwriting the rcParams so that my plot can have the size I defined?

Comment: What do you mean? Uncommenting the line changes the style, then your call to `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 8]` changes the figure size. Are you saying this doesn't happen on your machine?

Comment: Just to clarify, setting a style is equivalent to setting a whole bunch of stuff in the global configuration, a.k.a. `rcParams`.